# Redirecting when i hit save button with values

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, dynamic-visualforce

i want to create a code that when i hit save button i want to save the data and redirect it to a another view page with same values. I tired several method, but it does not work. Anybody have any idea? Thanks

```
<apex:page standardController="Product_Brief__c" sidebar="true" showHeader="true" extensions="gibco" ><br/>
apex:form ><br/>
        apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit"><br/>
            apex:pageBlockSection collapsible="false" title="Section 1: Custom Media Information (Required)"><br/>
                apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Opportunity__r.Account.Name}"  Label="Company Name"/><br/>
                apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Customer_Number__c}" label="Customer Number"/><br/>
                apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Billing_Address__c}" /><br/>
                apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.CreatedBy.Name}"  Label="Contact Name"/><br/>
                apex:outputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Shipping_Address__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection><br/>

apex:pageblockButtons ><br/>
                apex:commandButton action="{!save&view}" value="SAVE"/><br/>
                apex:commandButton value="PRINT" onclick="window.print();"/><br/>
                apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/><br/>
            /apex:pageblockButtons><br/>
/apex:form>
```

Extensions

```
public class gibco {

    public Product_Brief__c pb {get;set;}
    public User u {get;set;}

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller {get;set;}
    public boolean bUpdate {get;set;}
    public string loggedinUserId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    public User u2 = [Select ContactId From User where Id =: '005R0000001Y6h4'];

    public String ctId{
        get {
         //   if (ctId==null){
         //   if (bUpdate){
                  ctId = u2.ContactId;
         //       }
              return ctId;
         //   }
        }
        set;
    }

    Contact ct = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE id=:ctId];
    public string getacct(){
        Account acct = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE id=:ct.AccountId];  
        return acct.Name;
        return null;
        }

    Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId=:ct.AccountId LIMIT 1];

    public PageReference save&view() {
    if(controller.save() != null) {
    PageReference congratsPage = Page.page1;
    congratsPage.setRedirect(true);
    congratsPage.getParameters().put('id',controller.getId());
    return congratsPage;
    }  return null;
    }




    public PageReference page1(){
    return Page.gibcopb;
    }

    public PageReference page2(){
    return Page.gibcopb2;
    }

    public gibco(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If its another visualforce page, have the second page take in the object your saving as its controller.

The flow will be:

1) Save your object once you click save

2) Return a pagereference on your save method - return the page with the url '/apex/mysecondpage?id='+myObject.ID;

3) On your second page, query the data (WHERE id=:myObject.ID) and display accordingly.